# font-weight property and <b>/<strong>tag will not bold my Google Font. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I have imported [Comic Neue](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Comic+Neue?preview.text=Super%20Resturant!&preview.text_type=custom#standard-styles) as my font in html. However, when I try to set the h1 font to bold in css with font weight, it will not allow me to. I also tried setting my entire body to bold with no resolve. I tried editing the html to set the h1 element to bold as well. It seems to blink on the page and stay the same when reloading the page. Edit: I included all of my code. Sorry I am new to this...

**HTML/with header**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SuperRestaurant</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/gceEny9cd.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
    <div class="hero_image">
      <nav>
        <div class="topnav">
          <div class="left">
            <a href="C:/Users/Kascey.Malone/Documents/Websites/Midterm/midterm.coupons.index.html">
              <p>Coupons!</p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <a href="#Order">
              <p>Order Online!</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </header>
  <!--HERO SECTION-->
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>Super Restaurant!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="center">
        <button><a href="#menu">View Our Menu!</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--MENU TABLE-->
  <!--inspiration for menu: https://artsdistrictkitchen.com/ -->
  <div class="table">
    <table  id="menu">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Menu</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="">Beverages & Drinks</a></td>
          <td>Burgers</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="">Appetizers </a></td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="">Snacks & Sides</a></td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="">Main Dishes</a></td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="">Desserts</a></td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Item & Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--ABOUT | Two Column Layout-->
  <div class="about">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <h2>
          Our Story!
        </h2>
        <img
          src="C:/Users/Kascey.Malone/Documents/Websites/Midterm/images/6019677307b15.png"
          alt="Restaurant in 2007 with owner Benjamin Cookin.">
        <img
          src="C:/Users/Kascey.Malone/Documents/Websites/Midterm/images/saltz-restaurant.jpg" alt="">

        <img
          src="C:/Users/Kascey.Malone/Documents/Websites/Midterm/images/Plead-5th.jpg" alt="">

      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sollicitudin, ante non congue porttitor, ex
          metus
          interdum lectus, in tincidunt leo justo eu tortor. Nulla elementum elit et tortor vulputate congue. Phasellus
          turpis
          quam, luctus sit amet dapibus at, elementum at libero. Quisque convallis quis risus ut interdum. Nullam
          tincidunt vel
          magna non hendrerit. Nullam interdum turpis in risus congue fermentum. Vestibulum aliquam a leo vel mollis.
          Phasellus
          commodo urna vel libero commodo gravida. Ut egestas mollis nulla a maximus. Curabitur in est erat.
          Pellentesque sit amet
          eros nisi. Fusce ultricies tellus id hendrerit porta. Fusce commodo sit amet ex non volutpat. Integer quis
          mattis nisl.
          <br>
          Duis vitae dolor nec dolor suscipit tincidunt. Sed accumsan sodales mauris, vitae consectetur neque lobortis
          ut.
          Suspendisse vel sagittis lorem. Etiam vitae lacus a orci fermentum congue vitae non arcu. Donec nec leo
          fermentum,
          molestie leo non, elementum eros. Integer vitae cursus dolor, aliquam ullamcorper orci. Vivamus dignissim
          ullamcorper
          dapibus. Nunc aliquam sagittis aliquam. Nullam molestie aliquet urna eget venenatis. Pellentesque faucibus
          volutpat
          porta. Ut ac commodo velit, eget blandit arcu. Integer eu eros pulvinar, convallis odio et, ornare magna.
          Aliquam at
          rhoncus erat. Morbi rhoncus sapien sed dui vestibulum, pharetra vulputate purus elementum.
          <br>
          Nam eget vestibulum risus. Sed sollicitudin ultrices mi viverra luctus. Donec eu lacus placerat, ultricies leo
          quis,
          commodo diam. Sed consequat tristique mattis. Proin pulvinar aliquet leo, et auctor nunc euismod eu. Ut nisi
          turpis,
          vehicula dapibus iaculis nec, faucibus sed turpis. Phasellus non sapien sapien. Duis sed turpis eu lacus
          tristique
          dapibus. Phasellus consequat enim est, et tristique mauris efficitur quis. Nam dictum sit amet massa a
          vulputate.
          Suspendisse porta accumsan bibendum. Nullam id quam vel tellus hendrerit laoreet ac nec augue. Nulla massa
          mauris,
          pharetra sit amet lorem nec, interdum porttitor elit.
          <br>
          Donec eget vehicula magna. Etiam viverra quam nec metus euismod mattis. Phasellus ligula mauris, faucibus et
          luctus et,
          tincidunt ut dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc sagittis sodales lacus, at feugiat mauris mattis a.
          Integer
          et urna pharetra, dictum nibh ac, hendrerit tellus. In vestibulum ut nibh sed eleifend. Fusce ac volutpat
          felis.
          <br>
          Praesent sed suscipit justo, eu dictum erat. Aenean hendrerit malesuada arcu eget pharetra. In placerat erat
          purus, sit
          amet venenatis lectus semper ut. Praesent ut augue vitae libero accumsan mattis at id felis. Fusce lectus
          nisi,
          fermentum at lorem eu, consectetur sagittis mauris. Maecenas id fringilla felis, sit amet porttitor nisi. Sed
          eget leo
          magna. Sed eget felis dolor. Pellentesque dapibus eget elit ac pulvinar. Donec placerat facilisis enim, eu
          convallis
          ante varius a. Sed ac arcu cursus, imperdiet mauris at, dictum augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
          ipsum primis
          in faucibus. Proin mauris ipsum, varius nec viverra vitae, varius sed mi. Mauris venenatis, leo ac eleifend
          tempor,
          tortor mi auctor justo, ut placerat nisl leo eu odio. Cras pharetra facilisis lacus a aliquet.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </main>
  <!--FOOTER | Google Number-->
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <h3>PHONE</h3>
      <p><a href="#">000.000.0000</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <h3>ADDRESS</h3>
      <p>Super Restaurant!<br>
        100 University Pkwy<br>
        Macon, GA 31206</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <h3>© Super Restaurant! 2022. All rights reserved.</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* 
COLORS:
Dark Red:#9A1000
Dark Blue:#0C026C
Red:#FF1B00
Blue:#3823FC
Yellow:#FCD90A
White:#FFFFFF
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
}

main {
  margin-top: none;
}

.hero_image {
  background-image: url("C:/Users/Kascey.Malone/Documents/Websites/Midterm/images/669.png");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

/*NAVIGATION BAR*/
header {
  height: fit-content;
}

header a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FCD90A;
}

header a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.left {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
}

/*HERO BOX*/
.hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero h1 {
  font-size: 15vw;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #9A1000;
  font-style: italic;
}

.hero button {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  background-color: #FCD90A;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
}

.hero button a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }

.hero button a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
.hero button a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
.hero button a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
.hero button a:active {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*MENU TABLE*/
.table {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 1vw;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 8px black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}/*Add border.*/

thead {
  text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

td:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

table a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  } /*Change color based off background*/

table a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
table a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
table a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
table a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

th {
  padding: 10px;
}
/*ABOUT TEXT*/

.about {
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  padding-bottom: 5vh;
  background-color: #3823FC;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column h2{
  font-size: 2vw;
  padding-left: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.column p{
    padding-right: 200px;
    padding-top: 88px;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    color: white;
}
.column img {
    width: 30vw;
    padding-left: 200px;
    height: auto;
}


/*FOOTER*/
  .footer {
    background-color: #0C026C;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Edited*

Did you download the entire font-family? Or select just a few styles?

You could try replacing your imported font with a built-in CSS font and see if the bold property works. If the bold property works on the built-in font then you know the imported font is the issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems to just be the imported font! Going to try another!

Comment: Check my new answer below. It could be your css. Try .hero > h1 { font-weight: 700;}

Answer (score 0):

You can select any style of text on google fonts just click the bold 700 or up options and I could not find that you have even imported the font.
And you can easily change the boldness within the import link. The higher the number the biggest the boldness of the parts that I have highlighted in the import link are the numbers to change.

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue:wght@`700`&family=Orbitron:wght@`500`&display=swap');

Comment: Sorry. I added my head tag. I selected the bold italic font and was trying to select it in the CSS. I used `font-weight: 700`; and `font-weight: bold`. Then added the `font-style: italic;`.

Comment: Did it Work Though You can change it in the link too (the boldness)?

Comment: No. I added all the typefaces. All seem to work but 700 italic. I tried linking only the font I needed and it still didn't take. Trying to import next.

Comment: do the import instead of link

Answer (score 0):

You should check what weights [the font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Comic+Neue?query=Comic%20Neue) you are using contains.

You can select the weights you want and copy the css code from the side panel.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue:wght@300;400;700&display=swap");

p {
    font-family: "Comic Neue", cursive;
    font-size: 5vw;
    padding: 1vh;
}

p::after {
    content: attr(class);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: #000;
    color: gold;
    margin-inline-start: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

p.weight-300 {
    font-weight: 300;
}

p.weight-400 {
    font-weight: 400;
}

p.weight-700 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
    <p class="weight-300">Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
    <hr />
    <p class="weight-400">Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
    <hr />
    <p class="weight-700">Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried both `font-weight: 700;` and `font-weight: bold;` with no resolve. It works with no font imported but when I try to import Comic Neue. Nope.

Comment: As far as I checked the dude code, there is an excess/missing tag in the html. I suggest you to check the csste comments, there is something wrong there too. Other than that it seems to work on my system. If you could state more clearly where exactly you are in the problem, I might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your CSS:

```
.hero h1 {
   font-weight: 700//bold;
}
```

Try this in your css:

```
.hero > h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: The italics work but not the bold. Maybe its the font? I should have make it clear that I am trying to implement  `font-style: italic;` **and `** font-weight: 700;`. That is where it is giving me trouble.

Comment: I copied your code exactly in CSS and HTML and changed nothing and it worked for me. Even using your Google Font Link in HTML. What web browser are you using? This worked in Internet Explorer, Edge, and Chrome.

Also, you have Font-Weight: 700//Bold; in your CSS it should be Font-Weight: 700;

Comment: I am using VSCode and Chrome. I have changed the font weight in my original code with no resolve.